# Enable all text fields but not the file field

Tags: jquery, each, disabled-input

I'm trying to enable every text field I call in this function, but I do not want to enable the `type="file"` field. What happens, is that the `type="file"` field is being enabled anyway. Have I missed something?

```
function disabled_fields(fields, state) {
    if(state == true) {
        $(fields).each(function() {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        });
    } else {
        if(state == false) {
            $(fields).each(function() {
                if($(this).attr('type') != 'file') {
                    $(this).attr('disabled', false);
                }
            });
        }
    }
};

// Runs like this
disabled_fields('input, textarea', false);
```

Comment: What happens if you try `.prop("disable", true)` for everything? and another note: you don't have to check for state, you can directly set state as `true` or `false`.

Comment: add a fiddle that will make it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.not()` to exclude the elements,

```
function disabled_fields(state) {
    $("input,textarea").not("[type='file']").prop("disabled", state);
}
```

also note that, you dont have to loop through each elements to set the disabled property.

Comment: Damn, ninja'd me :p

You can also do it shorter like this `.not(':file')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
function disabled_fields(fields, state) {
    if (state == true) {
        $(fields).each(function () {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        });
    } else if (state == false) {
        $(fields).not("[type='file']").each(function () {
            $(this).attr('disabled', false);
        });
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/od2hufvm/)